# как повысить качество генератора слов без словаря

Tags: алгоритм, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Как повысить качество генератора слов без словаря?

Имеется код, но он не выдаёт качество как язык английского языка. Как же сделать без словаря понятные слова? Сымитировать, ссимулировать человеческий язык, качество языка.

```
program Hello;
uses
   sysutils;
var
   cons,vocs: ^string;
   letters:array[1..120] of ^string;
   i, cnt:integer;
begin
  new(cons);
  new(vocs);
  for i:=1 to 120 do
    new(letters[i]);
  cons^ := 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz';
  vocs^:='aeiouy';
  randomize;
  
  for i:=1 to 120 do begin
    write(cons^[random(20)]);
    write(vocs^[random(6)]); 
    if (random(2) = 0) then write(' ');
  end;
  
  cnt:=1;
  for i:=1 to 120 do
  begin
   
  end;
  
  dispose(cons);
  dispose(vocs);
  for i:=1 to 120 do
    dispose(letters[i]);
end.
```

Comment: Можно взять в интернете частоты буквосочетаний в русском языке. И ориентироваться на эти буквосочетания, из них слова набирать попробовать.

Comment: Уберите ^ и new-dispose, это просто не нужно

Answer (score 3):

Все упирается в частоты не просто букв, со сочетаний (слогов). Можно строить большие частотные таблицы 3-4-буквенных сочетаний. и генерировать по ним — только и объем памяти будет огромный, и работа такие таблицы построить еще та...

Но есть вариант попроще, кто в детстве Мартина Гарднера читал, знает :) — берем большой текст, выбираем букву. Идем по тексту, пока не встретим такую же, записываем ту, что идет за ней, и повторяем поиск уже новой буквы. Да, **это не строго случайный текст**, но...

Только так "русскоподобные" слова не получатся, надо хотя бы 3-4 буквы отслеживать для следующей. C одной буквы получится бред типа

> и столь сло ня р жорекаморе гиру ненил Обней, стьсм мака Ралебо ойстьцол чтомнор Нучто со.

Если брать две и искать третью - уже получше

> казместь и еднизу дождут вперевется, мнестные, ящил в гражданским движением. с жавше са ещетями, ям то, рукиновило и еще делист?

А вот с трех четвертую — считай, нормальный текст:

> ие ни старый лучине будете? Дожденностическая активную борьбу с революционным рабочим и фермерским движением.  в тюрьму

В качестве текста использованы "Гроздья гнева" Стейнбека.

Comment: как же тогда был сделан человеческий язык, если генератор не можете привнести качество в искусственный интеллект. Какие есть способы повысить качество генератора слов предложения?
Cколько слогов в русской языке? Как посчитать и написать такую функцию, которая бы возвращала массив строк слогов.

Comment: Человеческий язык никто не "делал", по сути, это результат естественного отбора. Разве что языки типа эсперанто, но они основаны на существующих языках... Выделение именно слогов — задача, как я понимаю, еще более тяжелая, чем просто сканирование текстов на пары/тройки символов, а уж вероятности встретить слог А после слога Б — тем более.

Comment: Кстати, вот и книжка на эту тему попалась — https://coollib.net/b/608027-svetlana-anatolevna-burlak-proishozhdenie-yazyika-faktyi-issledovaniya-gipotezyi